# Where can I get the javadoc for the Crystal Reports java API

Tags: java, crystal-reports, javadoc, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm working with objects such as the `IReportAppFactory`,`ISessionMgr`,`IEnterpriseSession`, `IInfoStore`, `IReport` and others from cecore.jar, celib.jar, ceplugins.jar, cesession.jar and  rasapp.jar, but there is no Javadoc attached. I have tried scouring the internet for them to no avail. Any links for the Javadoc? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Developer SDK Library](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27465) (BusinessObjects BI4).

You can also check the [online JavaDocs](http://help.sap.com/javadocs).

Comment: to be more specific here is the IReportAppFactory documentations https://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi/ras/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/managedreports/IReportAppFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

Some quick Googling found this: https://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi/boe/en/overview-summary.html, which looks like the javadoc for your library; if you click on the "all classes" link at the top, you can scroll down and find IReportAppFactory, ISessionMgr, etc.